# Unique token count speed

Tags: python, nlp

I'm attempting to turn a list of documents (each document is a list of tokens) into the format generally used by the [Blei Lab](https://github.com/Blei-Lab/) topic estimation routines where a document of `['token1', 'token4', 'token1']` becomes `2 1:2 4:1`. I'm able to generate the unique counts, but only very slowly.

```
token_list = sorted(set([stem for document in clean_tokens for stem in document]))

# token_nums = [[token_list.index(tok) for tok in document] for document in clean_tokens]
token_nums = []
for document in clean_tokens:
    document_nums = []
    for tok in document:
        document_nums.append(token_list.index(tok))
    token_nums.append(document_nums)    

counters = [Counter(document_nums).items() for document_nums in token_nums]
tok_strs = [' '.join([str(a[0]) + ':' + str(a[1]) for a in count]) for count in counters]
```

The second line (commented out, rewritten as loop for readability) is where my performance is really terrible. For each document, the inner list comprehension is searching through the whole `token_list` in order to find the correct index in the overall list of tokens. This then has to happen for each document.

How can I speed up this process of searching for all of these indexes?

If there's a more efficient way of performing the whole process, I'd appreciate hearing about that too.

Comment: Your use of generator makes it difficult to read, better break it down, and explain a bit what are the different variables.

Comment: @zyxue Better? I'm starting to think that this is really a question of how to speed up the `token_list.index()` call.

Comment: I am trying to understand it, but it's still confusing. You could just use nested for loops, which is more readable. What's the purpose of `token_list.index()`? If you're trying to count tokens, what about `document.count()`?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to simply count them. I'm assigning a unique index to each word and then exchanging all of the words for those unique indexes.

Comment: Your naming is really confusing, on the first line, you have `for document in clean_tokens`, and the nested loop, `for statement in clean_tokens`, so `document` equals `statement`? Similar issue with `statement_nums` and `state_toks`? What is document? I am kind of getting what you want now, you want the all tokens and its corresponding indexes in a document?

Comment: Sorry about the variable names, corrected. A document is a list of tokens. For each document, I need the list of unique tokens (as indexes of the master token list) along with the count of each unique token in the given docuement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead of .index, something like this

```
dd = dict((i, k) for k, i in enumerate(token_list))

for document in clean_tokens:
    print [dd[x] for x in document]
```